# Помогите решить проблемму с выборкой Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3, jquery-ui

Доброго времени суток!

[Здесь есть кнопка](http://jsfiddle.net/ptd019cz/), создающая атомы углерода с разными номерами, чтобы можно было проводить манипуляции с каждым атомом отдельно (например, перетаскивать по экрану с помощью функции `draggable Jquery UI`). А также есть два `checkbox'a`.
 Первый `checkbox` включает функцию, которая при клике на `h1` атома, создаёт знак `'+'`. Также работает второй `checkbox`, только создаёт другой знак - `'-'`. 
Атомы создаются конструктором, которые наследуют от прототипов методы, генерирующие заряды атома.

Например, мы создали атом и поставили на него знак `'-'`, отключив `checkbox` знака `'-'`, мы можем включить `checkbox` со знаком `'+'`. Когда мы кликаем по атому, знак `'-'` исчезнет и появится знак `'+'`. Также наоборот - когда первым был создан знак `'+'`, то знак `'-'` убирает `'+'` и появляется `'-'`.

Проблема в том, что когда несколько атомов имеют знаки `'+'` (`'-'`), то при попытке сменить один атом с `'+'` на `'-'`, меняются все на `'-'`.

Помогите разобраться, как сделать чтобы один атом, менял знак заряда, а не все сразу?

Comment: Довольно перегруженное описание, да и Ваш пример ничего не делает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял проблему, то для решения нужно заменить строки 69, 81 (в фидле) на: `$(".negative_charge", this).remove();` и  `$(".positive_charge", this).remove();` соответственно.

Второй параметр (`this`) в селекторе указывает узел в котором производить поиск. Благодаря ему `$(".positive_charge", this)` будет выбирать `+`(`-`) только внутри текущего элемента, а не во всём дереве.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!